# How to change the action of the home button in lightswitch VS 2013?

Tags: screen, visual-studio-lightswitch

I want to change the action of the home button in lightswitch. I mean, when I click here, the user should be redirected to another page.

[image: Click here should redirect to another page it another domain, and not to the home page]

Answer (score 2):

Following for home page.
Put your link in a div tag at msls-back-button-contain or msls-text

If you require link on each page, perhaps to consider a screen template.

```
myapp.Home.HomeGroup_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
var usersName;

//using a Promise object call the CallGetUserName function
msls.promiseOperation(CallGetUserName).then(function PromiseSuccess(PromiseResult)
{
    //set the result of the CallGetUserName function to usersName
    usersName = PromiseResult + " logged in.";

    //place users name in header
    $(element).closest("[data-role='page']").find(
    ".msls-screen-buttons").append(
    "<div style='color:#000000;font-size:16px;padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px'>" + usersName + "</div>");
});

    //clear the logout button from right of screen
    $(".msls-screen-buttons").empty();

    //clear home button container
    $(element).closest("[data-role='page']").find(".msls-back-button-contain").empty();

    //clear heading text
    $(element).closest("[data-role='page']").find(".msls-text").empty();

    //add logo
    $(element).closest("[data-role='page']").find(".msls-back-button-contain").append(
    "<div style='text-align: center'><img src='Content/Images/MyLogo.png';alt='logo'></div>");

};
```

To find which div tag to use, in IE 10+, you could F5 to run in VS --> then when browser opens F12 for Developer Tools --> Ctrl + B --> then hover mouse over element and let click mouse --> then read the div in DOM Explorer.

There could be better ways to achieve this.
Hope this helps and points you in the right direction.